# ¿Cómo mantener sólo un valor cuando dos columnas tienen entradas en R?

Tags: base-de-datos, r, string

Tengo una base como esta: (Con cadenas de texto)

```
dummy <- data.frame(uno=c(NA, "1", "1", NA, "1", "1"), 
    dos=c("2", NA, "2", NA, "2", "2"))

dummy


   uno  dos
1 <NA>    2
2    1 <NA>
3    1    2
4 <NA> <NA>
5    1    2
6    1    2
```

Como se aprecia, los renglones 3, 5 y 6 tienen valores en las dos columnas y sólo me interesa que se mantenga el valor de dichos renglones en la primera columna. En otras palabras, alcanzar este resultado:

```
   uno  dos
1 <NA>    2
2    1 <NA>
3    1  <NA> 
4 <NA>  <NA>
5    1 <NA>
6    1  <NA>
```

Intenté esto

```
dummy %>% 
    mutate(dos= ifelse(uno=="1" & dos=="2", NA, dos)) -> dummy2
```

pero regresa sólo NA para la segunda columna:

```
   uno dos
1 <NA>  NA
2    1  NA
3    1  NA
4 <NA>  NA
5    1  NA
6    1  NA
```

Lo que me interesa hacer podria ser expresado de la siguiente forma:

```
"Si el renglón N tiene valores (cualesquiera que sean) para las columnas 1 y 2, sólo mantener el valor de N para la primera columna".
```

Cualquier orientación la agradeceré muchísimo.

Answer (score 0):

Creo entender la pregunta... si hay un `1` en la columna `uno` se debe mantener, pero sí a su lado hay un número `2`, -en la columna `dos`- debe ser reemplazado este último por `NA`.

Sobre el particular, existe un método para verificar si una columna contiene `NA's` y es `is.na`

```
!is.na(dummy$uno)
# FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Lo anterior puede emplearse para filtrar en este caso qué valores de la columna `uno` no son (`!`) `Na`

```
dummy[!is.na(dummy$uno),]
#   uno  dos
# 2   1 <NA>
# 3   1    2
# 5   1    2
# 6   1    2
```

Entonces resumiendo, **la solución** para el ejemplo que se expuso, sería asignar a la columna `dos` el `NA` para aquellos valores que no son `NA` en la columna `uno`

```
dummy[!is.na(dummy$uno),2]<-NA
dummy
   uno  dos
1 <NA>    2
2    1 <NA>
3    1 <NA>
4 <NA> <NA>
5    1 <NA>
6    1 <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no estás planteando la lógica como la pide el enunciado. Esto:

```
dummy %>%
    mutate(dos = ifelse(uno=="1" & dos=="2", NA, dos))
```

Solo configura `NA` en la segunda columna si la primera tiene un `1` y la segunda un `2`, que no es el caso de la primer observación. La lógica usando `dplyr` sería algo así:

```
dummy %>% 
    mutate(dos = ifelse(is.na(uno), dos, NA))
```